# How to design the footprint when the pin positions are slightly different for each part?

Tags: footprint, nixie

I'm a beginner of electronics. I have several IN-12A nixie tubes. I want to mount the nixie tube on the PCB. However, the position of the pin in the [datasheet](http://danyk.cz/in-12_04.png) is out of the position of the pin in the nixie tube. 
[image]

Also, since the pins are slightly twisted with each other, adjusting the library to one nixie tube can cause problems when replacing nixie tubes. **How do I arrange holes to design a library that fits all IN-12A Nixie tubes?(I use the pins of D'SUB instead of Nixie Socket.)**

Answer (score 6):

PCBs and tubes don't mix well for that very reason the pin tolerances of tubes are too high and bending pins of a tube isn't an option either.

So the answer is to **use a proper tube socket**. These are made for that purpose, their individual contacts wiggle inside the socket housing to account for the manufacturing tolerances of the tube.

Comment: I live in the Republic of Korea and it takes too long to buy tube sockets. Is there any way to adjust PCB holes?

Comment: No. Each tube is unique in how the pins are slightly off. And don't even think about making the holes in the PCB bigger and use solder to fill up the gap. This would break the solder and/or the tube as the tube heats up and gets colder a number of times. If you can't have a tube socket, you have to solder stranded wire to the pins so there is a way for the mechanical forces to relieve. Don't laugh about that, it was a common practice in many small devices.

Comment: Is there no way to use D'SUB at all?

Comment: You can use the individual DSUB contacts if you put them into a housing where they can wiggle in. Again, use a stranded wire to connect the contacts with the board.

Comment: Make the hole bigger to accommodate for tolerance. If the pins are let's say tilted towards center, make an elongated hole rather than a circular one. Make sure all holes are radially aligned towards center.